# How to alter labels in Mapbox Streets in Mapbox Studio

Tags: labeling, mapbox, cartocss

I am creating vector tiles in Mapbox Studio v5 based off of the MapBox Streets layer.  I want to alter the labels that appear over buildings, parks, schools, churches etc. but I cannot find the code that deals with these labels.  I found the housenum_label section of the code but that does not deal with building or area names.  How can I change the style of these labels?

Here's an example of the labels I want to alter:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this:  The POI labels stylesheet is styled based off of scale rank.  I can't seem to find out a POI's scale rank but by removing the line of code:
 `[scalerank>4]`

I can style all the POI's which are the name tags from OpenStreetMap.